# Angular 2 Router issue, seeing errors in Developer tools console in platform-browser.umd.js

Tags: angular2-routing

I am trying to implement angular 2.0 Routing and I am seeing errors in console window:

I have tried  in Visual studio project but it doesn't work.

Below are example plunkers : I got solution to solve issue with  EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: '' by putting empty routes:

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/jJeQsLBOVrCz8QkxNAEc?p=preview --> this one has issue with routes which we can see on developer tools console

After replacing routes with empty route:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7rfrj2uXW0NYEoUg2gtP?p=preview --> this fixed issue with routes only on plunker but the same code in Visual studio project the error is not going away :(

so the routing error and Error with routes " in in platform-browser.umd.js in console window is still there in visual studio project 2015.

This is not fixing in my Visual Studio project any one got soluting for this ?

Also even after replacing with

`<base href="/">`

or

`<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`